# Ways to skip user consent in OpenID Connect

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-provider, openid-connect

In the Authentication Request, if users previously gave consent to some client (for a specific list of scopes) and because they might be prompted for the same authorization multiple times. ¿Could be acceptable to skip it?. ¿Works on both code and implicit flows?. ¿How much time remember the consent?.

I'm a little bit confused about the way to implement this. The Oauth2 draft say:

```
... and obtains an authorization decision
(by asking the resource owner or by
establishing approval via other means).
```

And OpenID draft say:

```
... this MAY be done through an interactive dialogue with the End-User
that makes it clear what is being consented to or by establishing
consent via conditions for processing the request or other means
(for example, via previous administrative consent).
```

Am working on an OpenID Provider implementation for Django.
https://github.com/juanifioren/django-openid-provider

Thanks for your time. Greetings.

Answer (score 2):

Consent is a tricky business. There are different rules in different countries and even different interpretations within the same country. But that aside a common way of handling consent in SSO systems is to ask the user for consent the first time she appears from a specific client and then also ask if the choice should be remembered or if it should only be valid this once. Of course if the user says her consent should be remember she still should have the possibility to later redraw the consent but then outside the normal authorization flow.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask for approval for a specific client only the first time that a user logs in to that client and then store it for later usage. In some use cases user consent is not required because it may be implicit, e.g. in an enterprise setting where users use internal clients.

Comment: Understood, but ... should I store the consent on a new entity or use Access Token to see if the client has user approval?.